# PhpStorm and git: how to commit auto before checkout

Tags: git, phpstorm

How to commit project automatically before change branch in PhpStorm?
Because, when I return on master without commit, my code changed too...

Comment: I would try it with GIT-Hooks (https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)

Answer (score 0):

You can't commit automatically in PHPStorm when you checkout master. You can use git in command line interface to stash your changes to be sure not to lose them, and then you checkout another branch. Then you reapply the stash.

```
git add .
git stash
git checkout master
git stash apply # or pop, it depends if you want to remove the stash completely
```

IDE are great for git, but they don't offer as many features as the command line client.